# REGEX: string replacement using named groups on Octave

Tags: regex, matlab, octave

I'm aware of the Pythonic way to replace a pattern in a `String` using named groups:

```
r"(?P<p>(\.+))".sub(r' \g<p> ', 'test sentence..')
```

Is it possible to do it on Octave (I'm using v3.8.0)? I tried some variations, as below, but no success.

```
regexprep('test sentence..', '(?<p>(\.+))', ' \k<p> ')
regexprep('test sentence..', '(?<p>(\.+))', ' $<p> ')
```

As you may have notice, this simple example focus on capturing the `String` `'..'` and adding a space before and after it.

```
Input: 'test sentence..'
Expected Output: 'test sentence .. '
Group Match: p = '..'
```

I'm able to capture the match normally using `$1`, `$2`, etc but not as named token.

Comment: Do you mind telling us what the regex is meant to capture and providing a test case (rather than using the variable `word`) so we don't have to do all of that work. Runnable code is always preferable.

Comment: Well, since the real question is why it is not working on MATLAB and not what the regex should capture, I've simplified the regex and included an example.

Comment: Your named token example (i.e., the second one, `' $<p> '`; the other one isn't valid) seems to work just fine in R2013b. What `version` are you using?

Comment: I'm on R2012b. I've tested on Octave 3.8.0 too and it did not work. Let me see if there is a bug fix on the release note of R2013b about it.

Comment: I still have R2012b too. I just ran the same line of code there and it worked fine. Are you sure that your example does what you think it does? Octave appears to use a different format for token naming. [See here](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/regexp.html). You may want `' ?<p> '`, but I can't test this.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Just tested here with the replacement pattern as `' ?<p> '` both on MATLAB R2012b and Octave. Unfortunately I'm not getting the desired replacement. I'm sure the example does what I want because it returns the correct answer if I use `' $1 '` (first match). Have you executed exactly the code I posted and got the expected output (shown above)? Are you using `regexprep`?

Comment: Yes, I copy/pasted `regexprep('test sentence..', '(?<p>(\.+))', ' $<p> ')` into my Matlab command window and the output was `'test sentence .. '`.

Comment: Ok, I think we narrowing down the problem. The problem is not MATLAB then. I got it working on command window. The same line does not work on Octave. I will replace MATLAB by Octave in the title.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Helps a lot.

Comment: Might this be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244838/matlab-regular-expressions-capture-groups-with-named-tokens/49226288#49226288 (Matlab only capturing tokens from the outermost set of parentheses)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @horchler  help, we have narrowed down the problem and it seems only Octave present the described problem. From Octave documentation, we have:

> Built-in Function: outstr = regexprep (string, pat, repstr) Built-in
>   Function: outstr = regexprep (string, pat, repstr, "opt1", ...)
>   Replace occurrences of pattern pat in string with repstr.
>
> The pattern is a regular expression as documented for regexp. See
>   regexp.
>
> The replacement string may contain $i, which substitutes for the ith
>   set of parentheses in the match string. For example,
>
> ```
>       regexprep ("Bill Dunn", '(\w+) (\w+)', '$2, $1') returns "Dunn, Bill"
> ```
>
> Options in addition to those of regexp are
>
> ‘once’ Replace only the first occurrence of pat in the result. 
>   ‘warnings’ This option is present for compatibility but is ignored.

So, they do not mention any support to `Named Tokens` as MATLAB documentation does. This makes me believe the current version of Octave does not support them along with `regexprep` function. As far as I know, a major concern of Octave developers is to make sure all MATLAB functionality is there at all, but it seems that one is still not supported.

Comment: Hmm. The top of the [`regexrep` documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/regexprep.html) implies it supports what `regexp` does: "The pattern is a regular expression as documented for regexp. See regexp." AS I mentioned in the comments, Octave's `regexp` uses it's own format for named tokens. So you tried `'(?<name>...)'` as is specified in the `regexp` documentation but it didn't work with `regexprep`?

Comment: Exactly. It does not work with `regexprep`. What it is supported is named tokens matching using `regexp`.